# React-Native ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Tags: ios, node.js, xcode, react-native, npm

I am TRYING to migrate to a better MacBook with better specs. My React-Native application `works perfectly on my MacBook Air` with same development environment as my new MacBook Pro. BUT when I run the same application on my new MacBook Pro, I get the following error.

[Screen Shot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1LSl.png)

It's so annoying that it works perfectly on the MacBook Air but not on the MacBook Pro.

I have spent two days and I have read the GitHub and all the StackOverflow pages and I've tried:

- killing processes on port 8081
- changing the port
- running it with `SUDO`
- updating react-native (I'm on the latest version)
- giving a relative address in the Xcode for build
- `Updating to latest version` AND ALSO TRIED `old and most stable version` of npm, node, Xcode and ....

I genuinely appreciate any insight, comment, help :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't define a bundle identifier in your Xcode project. 
Set your bundle identifier as shown in the screenshot:
[image: Xcode Bundle identifier]

You can also manually add the CFBundleIdentifier key to your Info.plist file located on ios/app-name/Info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.example.app</string>
```

Comment: The current Bundle Identifier is:  ‘org.reactjs.native.example.Empric’ should I change it?

Comment: @mansourjavaher Marco's answer should have solved the issue for you, is the problem still occurring after adding the `Bundle Identifier` and updating any `dependences`? If his answered worked, please accept it.

Comment: @mansourjavaher Thats really strange, but in that case I would just suggest react-native init again and then copy over all your files and reinstall your dependencies. That should resolve your problem :)